# Postfix: How to avoid forwarding spam (Spamassassin + Aliases)

Tags: postfix, spamassasin

We have a configuration where we have multiple shared IMAP folders (using dovecot) for a given group of people (e.g one for ressort A, one for ressort B). These groups have a mailaddress e.g. a@example.com and b@example.com. The people of this group can decide that they want the mail to be forwarded to an external account. (e.g. johndoe@another-example.com)

I implemented this using virtual_alias_maps (e.g. a@example.com -> a@example.com, johndoe@another-example.com)

now we have implemented spamassassin (postfix -> spamassassin -> postfix) where the first iteration does no alias resolution but just accepts the mail if the `rcpt to` address exists and the second iteration through postfix then resolves the aliases.

my problem is, that I do not want our server to actually send spam to those external accounts, but place the spam in a Spam/Junk folder on the local dovecot. so, I do not want the alias lookups to happen (or that they work differently) when the `X-Spam: yes` header is set.